# How can I load singleton class properties?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, singleton

I'am making a game, where I want to use Settings singleton class. I've got this sample of code from internet. But have a problem with loading this class. Can't understand how can I load these properties after saving.

```
class Settings: NSObject, NSCoding {

static let DocumentDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("settings")

static let shared = Settings()

var level: Int = 1
var moves: Int = 0
var music: Bool = true 

override init() {
    super.init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    level = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: SNames.CurrentLevelSName)
    music = aDecoder.decodeBool(forKey: SNames.MusicSName)
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(level, forKey: SNames.CurrentLevelSName)
    aCoder.encode(music, forKey: SNames.MusicSName)
}

func loadGame() -> Settings? {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Settings.ArchiveURL.path) as? Settings
}

func save() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self, toFile: Settings.ArchiveURL.path)
    if !isSuccessfulSave {
        print("Failed to save Settings...")
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a if let to get the settings and then you can access the level, moves and other properties. Heres some code.

```
if let settings = Settings.shared.loadGame() {
    print(settings.level)
}
```

This will load the settings and print the level.

Comment: I want to just load properties into this singleton class when I launch game in ViewController. And then from GameScene I want to access the level from shared instance. That's my problem.

Comment: Please try using my code in the GameScene. This code will load the class and then give you the level.